# PUSH-000191: Diffusion server: Too many open files

Tags: push-diffusion

I have an issue with my Diffusion server. The following error presents itself multiple times in the server logs:

```
|WARN|Client Connector Thread|PUSH-000191|Connector 'com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.
AcceptSelector$SelectorEventHandler@2f6b3a50:'
- Unable to accept connection.|com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.AcceptSelector 
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
```

I understand this might be due to too many file-descriptors being open. Anyone have any idea how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is displayed when the number of files (an associated file-descriptors) that can be concurrently open for one process is reached. This can be cause by few different reasons, such as:

- Part of your solution code is leaking file-descriptors (if you are using publishers).
- Your load-balancer is keeping TCP sockets open after use.

You can determine the current value of the maximum file-descriptor count imposed by your operating system by running the `JConsole` and checking the value in the `MBeans/java.lang/OperatingSystem/Attributes`. The data you need is under `MaxFileDescriptorCount` and `OpenFileDescriptorCount`. The warning you see is output when the `OpenFileDescriptorCount` reaches the limit set by `MaxFileDescriptorCount`.

In order to fix the issue, you need to increase the `MaxFileDescriptorCount` value. This can be done by modifying the start script for Diffusion. Simply add the following line to `diffusion.sh`:

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

This [Knowledge Base article](https://www.pushtechnology.com/support/kb/203651468-Too-Many-Open-Files-Error) contains more information around the issue that displays a `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` warning message.